# Using Mongoose Aggregation to Group By and Calculate Averages

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with the following structure:

```
    Prices: [ 
        exchange, symbol, volume, buy, sell, last, low, high
    ]
```

I am using Mongoose to query the records, and I'd like to get averages of buy, sell, last, low, high over the last 3 hours grouped by the symbol.

Essentially my goal is to display something like the following:
        (Let A, B, C, D, E, F be placeholders for numbers)

```
    Latest Prices for Exchange:
        Symbol A    Volume: A   Buy: B  Sell: C Last: D Low: E  High: F Spread: C - B
        Symbol B    Volume: A   Buy: B  Sell: C Last: D Low: E  High: F Spread: C - B

    3 Hour Averages for Exchange:
        Symbol A:   Volume: A   Buy: B  Sell: C Last: D Low: E  High: F Spread: C - B
        Symbol B:   Volume: X   Buy: B  Sell: C Last: D Low: E  High: F Spread: C - B
```

I've been reading through the MongoDB docs: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

To get the averages I've tried something like this:

```
    query = Prices.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$symbol",
                avg_last: { $avg: "$last" },
                avg_buy: { $avg: "$buy" },
                avg_sell: { $avg: "$sell" },
                avg_low: { $avg: "$low" },
                avg_high: { $avg: "$high" },
                averageSpread: { $avg: { $subtract: ["$sell", "$buy"] } },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

The problem is that there is no "condition" in this to limit the results to the past 3 hours.

Using the MongoDB Docs again for $cond 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

I've tried to apply this:

```
    var threeHoursAgo = new Date();
    threeHoursAgo.setHours(threeHoursAgo.getHours() - 3);

    query = Prices.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$symbol",
                avg_last: { $avg: "$last" },
                avg_buy: { $avg: "$buy" },
                avg_sell: { $avg: "$sell" },
                avg_low: { $avg: "$low" },
                avg_high: { $avg: "$high" },
                averageSpread: { $avg: { $subtract: ["$sell", "$buy"] } },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            },
            $cond: {
                exchange: strategy.primaryExchanges[i].exchange._id,
                timestamp: {
                    $gte: threeHoursAgo
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
"Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipline operators".
```

**EDIT:** I've also tried using $match like:

```
    query = Prices.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$symbol",
                avg_last: { $avg: "$last" },
                avg_buy: { $avg: "$buy" },
                avg_sell: { $avg: "$sell" },
                avg_low: { $avg: "$low" },
                avg_high: { $avg: "$high" },
                averageSpread: { $avg: { $subtract: ["$sell", "$buy"] } },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {exchange: strategy.primaryExchanges[i].exchange._id},
                    {timestamp: {$gte: threeHoursAgo} }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]);
```

but I get an empty array back.

**EDIT 2**
Here is a sample document from my Prices collection:

```
 {"_id":"ObjectId(56296ac0603c75c80b3d581f)","symbol":"XBT24H","contract":"XBT24H","exchange":"ObjectId(55dc8ae9ecb73538125ddd9a)","timestamp":"ISODate(2015-10-22T23:01:15.000Z)","volume":260475,"buy":275.41,"sell":275.7,"low":274.44,"last":275.7,"high":277.03,"__v":0}
```

Comment: `$cond` is not an a pipeline operator. please show us sample document with expected result.

Comment: Here are some sample documents. http://pastebin.com/XvUkZJks

It's pretty straight forward, the expected result is just an average of each of the fields. I've got it calculating these averages fine, that's not an issue. 

**The issue is adding the "where" clause to limit *which* results get included in the aggregation**

Comment: Why can't you edit your question to add those documents with the expected result?

Comment: It's a matter of calculating an average of a bunch of numbers? 

I didn't think it needed that much explanation seeing as how my problem isn't **how** to calculate an average, it's **how do I apply a condition to the aggregation**.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out the solution to this.

The problem was my $match declaration. had to be before my $group declaration

```
    query = Prices.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {exchange: strategy.primaryExchanges[i].exchange._id},
                    {timestamp: {$gte: threeHoursAgo} }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$symbol",
                avg_last: { $avg: "$last" },
                avg_buy: { $avg: "$buy" },
                avg_sell: { $avg: "$sell" },
                avg_low: { $avg: "$low" },
                avg_high: { $avg: "$high" },
                averageSpread: { $avg: { $subtract: ["$sell", "$buy"] } },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

This works and returns the results I was expecting.